# Music Player, writing metada

Tags: java, mp3

I was wondering if someone can help me with this:
I´m making a program of a music player. I´m using Jaudiotagger that helps me to read the metadata but I need to be able of overwrite that metadata too. Does anybody know how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: JaudioTagger supports writing the metadata - look at `AudioFileIO.write` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with jaudiotagger you read the file, get the tag and modify the metadata then use f.commit() to save the changes (or you can use AudioFileIO.write instead they do the same thing)

```
 AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
 Tag tag = f.getTag();
 tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST, "fred");
 .............
 f.commit();
```

Comment: I followed your answer but I am getting CannotWriteException while running on Android 6.0. My app's target sdk version is Android Lollipop which allows writing data to sd card AFAIK. Can you please suggest any solution?